# How to disable or truncating fields when printing in MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

I tried to query the Monetdb server. I am printing the columns in the table called Ada and the columns are truncated and only few columns are displayed. On the terminal, it says to avoid dropping or truncating the columns use `\w-1` but not sure how to use it in commands. 
I am new to use MonetDB so I need some help. Thanks
fram -> Database

The query i used to print columns:

```
>select * FROM fram.Ada LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just type `\w-1` in the sql prompt at mclient:

```
sql>\w-1
```

Fair warning though the result probably will not look that good. You can see a brief description of all the meta-commands valid in mclient by typing `\?`. Specifically for `\w` the description is:

> \w#      - set maximal page width (-1=unlimited, 0=terminal width, >0=limit to num)

So in order to go back to the previous behavior use `\w0`, or to format the result to use 120 character columns use `\w120`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by first running

```
>\w-1
>select * FROM fram.Ada LIMIT 3;
```